Why does my Rancher Desktop K8s service assign an external IP that is in an unreachable subnet?
When I create a new service defined as follows:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mealie
  name: mealie
  namespace: mealie
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: mealie
  type: LoadBalancer

I can access the app via http://localhost:9000. But I cannot access it by the service's external-IP, which is 192.168.5.15. The subnet my machine is on is 192.168.1.xxx, and so the app is unreachable.
I am using Rancher Desktop 1.13.1 on MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1.
I was expecting to be able to access the service by localhost or the external IP address, but I can only access it via localhost.
I have searched the web to see if there is a way to configure the allowable IP ranges, but was not able to find anything. I tried to do this on my Windows 11 machine, and everything worked normally - I was able to access the app in my browser by using localhost:9000 and also by using <service_external_ip>:9000.
Any help is appreciated!

Do you have required routes present on the system?
for macOS you can find a similar command and add required route:
On my Linux desktop, I would:
sudo route -n add 192.168.5.0/24 $(ifconfig en0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2}')


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
